# Swagger Editor shows the "Schema error: should NOT have additional properties" error for a path parameter

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm using http://editor.swagger.io to design an API and I get an error which I don't know how to address:

```
Schema error at paths['/employees/{employeeId}/roles'].get.parameters[0]
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: type, format, name, in, description
Jump to line 24
```

I have other endpoints defined in a similar way, and don't get this error. I wondered if I had some issue with indentation or unclosed quotes, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Google also did not seem to provide any useful results.

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: Initial draft of the API specification
  version: '1.0'
  title: App 4.0 API
host: api.com
basePath: /v1
tags:
  - name: employees
    description: Employee management
schemes:
  - https
paths:
  /employees/{employeeId}/roles:
    get:
      tags:
        - employees
      summary: "Get a specific employee's roles"
      description: ''
      operationId: findEmployeeRoles
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: employeeId   <====== Line 24
          in: path
          description: Id of employee whose roles we are fetching
          type: integer
          format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Role'
        '403':
          description: No permission to see employee roles
        '404':
          description: EmployeeId not found
```

Any Hints?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The actual error is that your path parameter is missing `required: true`. Path parameters are always required, so remember to add `required: true` to them.

Comment: I have `required: true` in my definition and I'm still getting that error.

Comment: In my case, I had required true and still the same error, found that the issue was indentation of get misplaced

Answer (score 34):

Had the same problem. I accidentally mixed up the syntax from `Swagger 2.0` with `Openapi 3.0.x`. In `Openapi 3.0.x`, **definitions are redefined as components**. In the [online editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) you can click on the button **Edit** > **Convert to OpenAPI 3** to use `Openapi 3.0.x`.

Read more about **components** [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/).

Remark:

> OAS 3 is the latest version of the
> OpenAPI Specification.

Comment: The tip to use the online editor to get a better error message was key to solving my problem.

Comment: your link to https://editor.swagger.io/ works, better error messages, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For me the cause of the error was a missing a leading slash in the path (`internal/resource` instead of `/internal/resource`).

And yes the error message is extremely unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was missing parameter definition in api definition

```
- name: parameterName
  in: query
  description: parameter's description here.
  required: false
  schema:
    type: string
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it had the wrong indentation for the example. It was:

```
              content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/someresponse'
            examples:
              example1:
                value:
                  param1: "some string"
                  param2: "123"
```

Rather than:

```
              content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/someresponse'
          examples:
            example1:
              value:
                param1: "some string"
                param2: "123"
```

But the VScode open api preview with swaggerUI didn't show any errors and everything looked valid.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax requires might require two parameters, as mentioned by Helen `required: true` is need so is `type:DataType` . The error is misleading.